# Unable to pass null-named parameters for the table using APIs in spring JPA

Tags: spring-data-jpa

I am unable to pass the null values (null, null) to the table-named parameters in APIs.

I tried with JDBCTemplate and it's working fine, but while trying to implement with APIs, I am getting the following error:

> 2023-04-10 18:10:09 [ERROR] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/].[dispatcherServlet] - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause
> java.lang.NullPointerException: null.

Could you please me on this.

Comment: We need more stack trace, ie that indicates the line in your code where the error arises. We also need the bit of your source code around the error source and relevant '@Entity' '@Repository' definitions.

Comment: @Entity @Table(name = "sys.tablename(NULL, NULL)") public class classname { ----- ----- ----- }